# How to programmatically detect Endeca indexing is successful (from ATG) to send an email?

Tags: atg, endeca

The requirement is that once the `Baseline Index` is successful, an **email** has to be sent to an admin automatically.

Is there any out-of-the-box feature available in ATG Endeca integration?  If not, how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

Extend `SimpleIndexingAdmin` class and override `indexBaseline()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mailer custom component for the AppConfig.xml that used to be available from Endeca.

Using a few lines of configuration, you can send email from anywhere in the scripts.

I do not know if Oracle still supports it.

The java class is called com.endeca.esource.dtmailerutility.MailNotificationComponent.

There is more info about it here:
https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2453483

Comment: Is this class part of Endeca Commerce (part of ATG Endeca integration)?

Comment: I dont know, but I do not think that it is. Unless that changed its name. You may want to check on Oracle community.